# Help Deleting 150 Million + Items from Trash on Mac

Tags: backup, time-machine, trash, macos

I have over 150 million files to delete on my Mac, and I've run all the versions of rm -rf ~/.Trash/* in Terminal and nothing has happened. Can somebody please explain to me how to delete these files quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Are the files on another disk? If they are, the Trash folder for those disks will be stored on those disks, not in ~/.Trash. For instance, if the files are on a disk called "Test", you'd run `rm -rf /Volumes/Test/.Trashes`.

Comment: @Faiz Saleem, If on another disk, then `sudo` will need to be used!